# Dealing with unencoded characters in submitted text

Tags: forms, encoding, submission

Form submissions with text sometimes include characters such as © or ™. The server receives them as Â© and â„¢ so I can't readily decipher them before saving them to a database.

How do I deal with them in the form itself? How are they being handled here, in this form?

Comment: This seems a normal encoding problem. Note: Characters are always encoded, but when printed. In your case, it seems that the form has Unicode code point, but the server read them as some Latin or windows cp. For sake of your sanity, you should always have a server which work on unicode (as default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` made the difference